# Write Cyrillic to RDF file using jena library

Tags: rdf, jena, cyrillic

I have an extracted Cyrillic content from a HTML page to a text file. The Cyrillic is OK in this file. Then I use this file to create a RDF file using Jena. Here is my code:

```java
private void createRDFFile(String webContentFilePath) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    RDFWriter writer = model.getWriter("RDF/XML");
    writer.setProperty("showXmlDeclaration", "true");
    writer.setProperty("showDoctypeDeclaration", "true");
    writer.setProperty("tab", "8");
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(rdfFilePath), "UTF8"));
    Resource resDest = null;
    Property hasTimeStart = model.createProperty(ns + "#hasTimeStart");
    Property distrName = model.createProperty(ns + "#distrName");
    Property moneyOneDir = model.createProperty(ns + "#moneyOneDir");
    Property moneyTwoDir = model.createProperty(ns + "#moneyTwoDir");
    Property hasTimeStop = model.createProperty(ns + "#hasTimeStop");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            webContentFilePath));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] arrayLine = line.split("\\|");
        resDest = model.createResource(ns + arrayLine[5]);
        resDest.addProperty(hasTimeStart, arrayLine[0]);
        resDest.addProperty(distrName, arrayLine[1]);
        resDest.addProperty(moneyOneDir, arrayLine[2]);
        resDest.addProperty(moneyTwoDir, arrayLine[3]);
        resDest.addProperty(hasTimeStop, arrayLine[4]);
    }
    br.close();
    model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML");
    writer.write(model, out, null);

}
```

When I open the RDF file the Cyrillic is like РўР РђРќРЎРљРћРџ-Р‘Р?РўРћР›Рђ.
Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

The UTF-8 write encoding on the output writer looks correct, so that suggests that you're not reading `webContentFilePath` with the correct encoding. As a diagnostic, you could try just reading that file in and then writing it out to a plain UTF-8 file (no RDF). My guess is that you will have to be explicit about setting the file encoding on `br`, or ensure that the scraped web page is written out in UTF-8 to begin with.

Comment: I was wrong. First I forgot the utf-8 encoding settings in the OutputStreamWriter, and then I didn't reload the file in the text editor I was opening with. Now in the text editor is OK, but in eclipse I still receive these strange characters.

Comment: So your file is OK, except when you open it in Eclipse? You should set the default encoding for Eclipse to UTF-8, see http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/29511/ for some suggestions, or other StackOverflow questions on a similar topic.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the output is correct, but you're not seeing it correctly.

new FileReader(...) will open the file with the platform-default character set.  This is not UTF-8 on Windows, so if it looks right, then you maybe viewing it in something other than UTF-8.

Jena writes in UTF-8 by default and in this case.

So when you write the file, you can not view it the same way you viewed the input.  You need to view it with a UTF-8 aware viewer.